# How to place 2 algorithms side by side?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to place two versions of an algorithm side by side.  Using depth first search as an example, I'd like to put the recursive version on the left column and iterative on the right side.  I'm using this [stack overflow post for python formating](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83883) and minipage.  The aforementioned commands don't work in minipage however as shown below.  How do I center the python code blocks in each minipage?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}


% Default fixed font does not support bold face
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{12} % for bold
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{12}  % for normal

% Custom colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage{listings}

% Python style for highlighting
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
    language=Python,
    basicstyle=\ttm,
    otherkeywords={self},             % Add keywords here
    keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
    emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
    emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
    showstringspaces=false            %
}}


% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]{
  \pythonstyle
  \lstset{#1}
}{}

% Python for inline
\newcommand\pythoninline[1]{{\pythonstyle\lstinline!#1!}}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \vspace*{10mm}
  {\bf {\huge General Notes}}\\
  \vspace*{5mm}
  {\bf {CS, ML and Stats}
    \\ \vspace*{2mm} {\large Patrick Daly}
  }
\end{center}

\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Computer Science}

\subsection{Algorithms}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item DFS %
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} %
      test
      \begin{python}
        def dfs(node):
            if node:
                # do stuff if pre-order
                if node.left:
                    dfs(node.left)
                # do stuff if in-order
                if node.right:
                    dfs(node.right)
                # do stuff if post-order
      \end{python}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} %
      test
      \begin{python}
        def dfs(node):
            if node:
                # do stuff if pre-order
                if node.left:
                    dfs(node.left)
                # do stuff if in-order
                if node.right:
                    dfs(node.right)
                # do stuff if post-order
      \end{python}
    \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

edit: I may need to autosize the font to squish the content in each column.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately your code fragment is not compilable.

Comment: missing \end{document}, fixed

Comment: Nope. Does not compile. Did you test the code fragment?

Comment: good now, part of code was not copied correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically rescaling of content that contains text is not a good idea, this will give you suboptimal font shapes. Instead you can

1. save a lot of space by not adding unnecessary indention from the tex source and
2. allow line breaks

In case this is not enough, you could manually choose a smaller font.

Some other comments:

- two minipages with each `.5\textwidth` won't fit besides each other if you use this within an enumerate environment. The remaining line after the numeration is only `\linewidth` wide, so even if there is no other text in the line, the minipages must not be wider than `.5\linewidth` each
- please don't load the same package more than once.
- `hyperref` should (with very few exceptions) be loaded last
- don't use two-letter font switches like `\bf`, they are deprecated

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}


% Default fixed font does not support bold face
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{12} % for bold
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{12}  % for normal

% Custom colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

%\usepackage{listings}

% Python style for highlighting
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
    language=Python,
    basicstyle=\ttm,
    otherkeywords={self},             % Add keywords here
    keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
    emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
    emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines            %
}}


% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]{
  \pythonstyle
  \lstset{#1}
}{}

% Python for inline
\newcommand\pythoninline[1]{{\pythonstyle\lstinline!#1!}}

%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \vspace*{10mm}
  {\bfseries {\huge General Notes}}\\
  \vspace*{5mm}
  {\bfseries {CS, ML and Stats}
    \\ \vspace*{2mm} {\large Patrick Daly}
  }
\end{center}

\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Computer Science}

\subsection{Algorithms}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item DFS %

    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}%
      test
\begin{python}
def dfs(node):
    if node:
        # do stuff if pre-order
        if node.left:
            dfs(node.left)
        # do stuff if in-order
        if node.right:
            dfs(node.right)
        # do stuff if post-order
\end{python}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}%
test
\begin{python}
def dfs(node):
    if node:
        # do stuff if pre-order
        if node.left:
            dfs(node.left)
        # do stuff if in-order
        if node.right:
            dfs(node.right)
        # do stuff if post-order
\end{python}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  In addition I'll create a python command specifically for two column that has a smaller font.